# A concise set of equation of physics that handles basic 2d physics for acceleration?

Tags: 2d, physics

I am making an Asteroids clone and I want to implement proper physics for the objects. What equations would I use to calculate the acceleration? For example, I have a ship, and it might have properties like mass and other stuff (whatever might be relevant, I don't know). If I assume thrust of 10 units, how would the ship accelerate over time in the given direction? There is no friction since the game is set in space, so I don't need to worry about deceleration.

When I Google formula for acceleration, it says `final velocity - starting velocity / elapsed time` but that's for calculating how much an already accelerating object is accelerating by isn't it? Or am I confused? Thanks for helping.

Comment: This is just grade 9 algebra to rearrange that equation to solve for final velocity, given starting velocity and your time step.

Comment: @DMGregory Ah, thanks. So that gives final = acc * time + starting. So the I have time and starting. Would I choose and arbitrary value for acceleration or would that depend of the physical system ?

Comment: [What does Wikipedia have to say about unit conventions for acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration)?

Answer (score 1):

I found that newtons second law of motion was what I was looking for.

`Force = Mass * Acceleration`.

Rearranging this gives us the acceleration.

`Acceleration = Force / Mass`

Then I am adding this amount to my objects velocity vector every frame.